# Batch frequency of point groups to single table in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, analysis, batch, frequency

I'm new in the GIS world.

I have a bunch of points (around 40,000), which are split in categories (1 to 9) and have a field which specifies their membership to a polygon (~50) (e.g, 30, which would mean that the point is located in polygon 30).

Some zones do not contain points of all categories.

I wish to know the frequency of each category per zone, in such a way that in the end I would have a table with the first column for the categories, and the zones listed in the first row.

Did somebody have the same challenge? How did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Being as though you have all of the info you require you could do this using a pivot table in Excel (just open and save a copy of the .dbf associated with your points shapefile).

In ArcGIS, you can also create a pivot table (i.e. Data Management > Table > Pivot Table) depending upon your licence level. Alternatively, you could use Summarise (click on the field header of the field you want to summarise). There's an ESRI article here: [Summarise tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//005s00000055000000)